# how to use auto increment id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script>
function show(id){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p") .toggle();
});
});
</script>
 <?php 
    $bid=0;
    $bid=0;
    include 'model.php';
    $db=new database;
    $r=$db->msghead($admno);
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($r))
    {
        $id=$row[0];
        $title=$row[1];
        $msg=$row[2];
        $date=$row[3];
        $sender=$row[4];
        $tit_status=$row["title_status"];
        $bid=$bid+1;
        $pid=$pid+1;
?>
<button style="width:80%;height:35px;" onclick="MessageDetailsById(<?php echo $id;?>)"   >


    <?php   
        if($tit_status=="1"){
    ?>      
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="width:20px;float:left;"></i>  <i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span id="active" class="sidebar-title" style="color:red;"><?php echo $title; ?></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $date;?>
<?php }else{?>      
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="width:20px;float:left;"></i> <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span  id="active<?php echo $tit_status;?>" class="sidebar-title"><?php echo $title;  ?></span>    &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $date;?>
<?php }?>
        </a></button>

<p style="display:none;" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">   <?php echo $msg; ?> 

      <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Reply
      </a>

</p>
<?php } ?>
```

so many buttons generated according to database.. but when i click single button all paragraph get open but i want it open only the paragraph related to its button.. i dont know which id will be used and how ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want(toggle current and hide all at the same time) for that you have to change your structure and do like below:-

***Example with your structure (you have to put your dynamic data carefully):-***

```js
$('.item p').hide();

$('.item button').click(function(e){
    
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('p');
    $(".item p").not($this).hide();
    $this.toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"> <!-- this is needed otherwise not possible -->
    <button>Button</button> <p>span1</p> <br>
</div>

<div class="item">
<button>Button</button> <p>span2</p><br>
</div>
    
<div class="item">
<button>Button</button> <p>span3</p><br>
</div>
    
<div class="item">
<button>Button</button> <p>span4</p><br>
</div>
```

Reference taken:- http://jsfiddle.net/BGSyS/3/

Answer (score 1):

you  are assigning id to `p`

```
<p style="display:none;" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

so just change your jquery code to this :

```
  function MessageDetailsById(id){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("#"+id) .toggle();
    });
  }
```

Comment: but how did my program get to know that which button i pressed

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p") .toggle();
    });
});
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
<button ... data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" ...>...</button>
<p ... data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" ...>...</p>
```

And then On click do something like:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('p').find("[data-id='" + $(this).data('id') + "']").toggle();
});
```

I have not tested but I do use this case with dynamic elements in my programs.