# jQuery/JS iteration inside html id index created in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a site like this
[image]

I creating these fields using for loop.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="toggle_visibility('dataHolder-@i');">
    <span id="day"> waiting...</span>
</a>

<div id="dataHolder-@i" style="display: none;" class="alert alert-dismissible alert-primary col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <b> City: </b> <span id="name.@i"> waiting...</span><br/>
            <b> Country: </b><span id="country.@i"> waiting...</span><br/>
            <b> Latitude: </b><span id="lat.@i"> waiting...</span><br/>
            <b> Longitude: </b><span id="lon.@i"> waiting...</span><br/>
            <b> Visibility: </b><span id="visibility.@i"> waiting...</span>m<br/>
            <b> Wind speed: </b><span id="wind.@i"> waiting...</span>meters/sec<br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <b> Humidity: </b><span id="humidity.@i"> waiting...</span>%<br/>
            <b> AvgPressure: </b><span id="pressure.@i"> waiting...</span>hPa<br/>
            <b> Temperature: </b><span id="temp.@i"> waiting...</span>&deg; C<br/>
            <b> Temperature feels like: </b><span id="tempfeelslike.@i"> waiting...</span>&deg; C<br/>
            <b> Min temperature: </b><span id="minTemp.@i"> waiting...</span>&deg; C<br/>
            <b> Max temperature:: </b><span id="maxTemp.@i"> waiting...</span>&deg; C<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>}
```

and there I want to display values from JSON that I send from the backend.

I'm using a function like this, but I have no idea how to add each value to the next container.

```
success: function(response) {
                var value = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(response);
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    $("#name.0").html(value.CityName);
                    $("#country").html(value.CountryName);
                    $("#lat").html(value.Coords[0].lat);
                    $("#lon").html(value.Coords[0].lon);
                    $("#humidity").html(value.DataByDay[0].AvgHumidity);
                    $("#tempfeelslike").html(value.DataByDay[0].AvgFeelsLike);
                    $("#visibility").html(value.DataByDay[0].AvgVisibility);
                    $("#wind").html(value.DataByDay[0].AvgWindSpeed);
                    $("#temp").html(value.DataByDay[0].AvgTemp);
                    $("#maxTemp").html(value.DataByDay[0].AvgMaxTemp);
                    $("#minTemp").html(value.DataByDay[0].AvgMinTemp);
                    $("#pressure").html(value.DataByDay[0].AvgPressure);
                    $("#day").html(value.DataByDay[0].DayTime);
                }
            }
```

EDIT:

I'm getting values like this [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use auto increment id in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231437/how-to-use-auto-increment-id-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Using classes rather than trying to use incremental ID is the simplest approach. Loop over each of those containers and use the index of the current loop iteration to match container index to array index

Simplified example:

```js
const data = [
  {"lat": 22, "lng": 33},
  {"lat": 27, "lng": 37},
  {"lat": 117, "lng": 77}
]

$('.data-holder').each(function(i){
   const dataItem = data[i];
   $(this).find('.lat').text(dataItem.lat);
   $(this).find('.lng').text(dataItem.lng)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<div class="data-holder">
   <p>Lat: <span class="lat"></span>, Long: <span class="lng"></span>
</div>
<div class="data-holder">
   <p>Lat: <span class="lat"></span>, Long: <span class="lng"></span>
</div>
<div class="data-holder">
   <p>Lat: <span class="lat"></span>, Long: <span class="lng"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's look easy but I'm not really know how to apply this to my solution.